# Batch. Заменить все файлы в папке другим файлом, сохраняя имена

Tags: windows, cmd, файлы

Первая папка "D:\Test\1" с файлом "0.txt" внутри.

Вторая папка "D:\Test\2" с несколькими файлами "1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt" и тд.

Я бы хотел заменить все .txt файлы во второй папке файлом из первой, но с сохранением имен файлов. 
Таким образом все файлы во второй папке будут копией файла из первой, но будут называться как и раньше "1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt" и тд.
Как только это будет сделано, все эти файлы нужно пометить как только для чтения. Если это возможно, конечно.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Например так:
перезапись -

```
for %i in (D:\Test\2\*.txt) do copy D:\Test\1\0.txt "%i" /Y
```

`/Y` - подавляет вопрос о перезаписи, это можно прочитать в справке `copy /?`.

установка атрибута ReadOnly -

```
for %i in (D:\Test\2\*.txt) do attrib r "%i"
```

**[Тут](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting)** есть еще много всякого про BAT-скрипты в CMD.